# Find the minimum of a vector ignoring certain numbers

Tags: r

I would like to find the minimum value a of vector but without including certain value

ex :

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,-9999 ,7 ,8 ,9)
```

And I want to avoid values 1 and -9999. So the answer here would be 2.

Comment: `min(a[!a %in% c(1, -9999)])`

Comment: @josliber Even mods put answers in comments! ;)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `setdiff` to include only those elements which we want and find the minimum among them.

```
min(setdiff(a, ignore))
#[1] 2
```

**data**

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,-9999 ,7 ,8 ,9)
ignore <- c(1, -9999)
```